# Why is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

What grammar elements have been used to construct such a sentence?

- *For music isn’t just something nice to listen to.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Why* part is easy. It's grammatically correct because it follows grammatical rules correctly.

But there are [a lot of English grammatical rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), and this sentence

- *For music isn’t just something nice to listen to.*

makes use of quite a few. This sentence has three clauses, two of them reduced clauses.

Plus, it starts with the coordinating conjunction *for*,
which indicates that it's conjoined to some unknown previous sentence.
Let's ignore the *for* part here, because we don't know what the previous sentence was.
(Though @BillJ's guess is as good as any)

- *Music isn’t just something nice to listen to.*

*Just* means *only* (in its sense 'of small importance'), so it's predictable.
And it's directly negated by the negative *isn't*, so the sense is reversed: 'of great importance'.
Again, predictably. And with the same essential structure as

- *Music is something nice to listen to.*

Let's start by putting back in the optional markers that have been optionally deleted

- *Music is something **that/which it is** nice **for `Indef`** to listen to.*

In this case, the chunks that have been deleted include

1. the relative pronoun *that* or *which* (inserted by the rule of Relative-Formation)
2. the dummy subject *it* (inserted by the rule of Extraposition)
3. the auxiliary verb *is* (required for all predicate adjectives like *nice*)
4. the infinitive subject marker *for* (part of the infinitive *for..to* complementizer)
5. the indefinite infinitive subject (the person(s) doing the listening: `Indef`).

Note that the sentences with and without the deleted chunks mean the same thing.

It's also possible to unwind other rules here. The dummy *it,* for instance, comes from Extraposing

- *For `Indef` to listen to music is nice for `Indef`*
  ==>  Extraposition  ==>
  *It is nice for `Indef` to listen to music*
  which gets rid of the double phrase *for `Indef`*; it's positioned to modify either way.

There's more to say; this sentence has been done a lot of things to.
But I'll stop here.

Comment: I very much dislike the term 'reduced relative clause', since the syntax is quite different to a ‘regular’ relative clause. Even if you were to expand it into a relative, the NP would simply be "just something that/which is nice to listen to", where the relative word "that"/"which" has "something" as its antecedent, so no extraposition required here. And why ‘conjoined to some unknown previous sentence’? As a PP, its salient function would be as supplement, i.e. the kind that is not conjoined at all, but are merely loose adjuncts, not tightly integrated into clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ Well, whichever way you look at this *for*, it doesn't seem to be a regular prep. For example, if it was a straightforward bona fide prep we'd expect it to be able to precede the clause it's modifying. However, this leads to ungrammatical results: *Let's forgo the music, for it isn't edifying* versus * *For it isn't edifying let's forgo the music*.

Comment: @Araucaria There is a restriction on for-phrases (as reason adjuncts) in that they can't occupy a position in front of the element they modify (or are supplementary to). In that respect it differs from "as" and "because", for instance.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, that's right. There's other reasons why *for* is problematic too. CaGEL discuss it's part co-ordinator, part preposition-like properties at some length ... :)

Answer (score 2):

First: it's not a sentence, but a preposition phrase headed by the prep *for*, which here has a meaning similar to *since* or *because*.

The complement of the prep *for* is the declarative clause *music isn't just something to listen to* in which *music* is the subject, and the NP *just something nice to listen to* a predicative complement in its ascriptive sense. Within that NP complement is the non-finite infinitival clause *to listen to*, which appears to be a relative clause.

In a contextual vacuum, it's a tad difficult to be 100% certain, but the PP is probably a reason adjunct from a larger unit, for example:

*It's not just a noise; it's an ideology, for/since/because music isn't just something nice to listen to.*